# CFPreferences Background Sync Queue Delaying my App?

Tags: ios, plist

I've been working on a jigsaw puzzle app. I was originally going to use core data to save the progress of the puzzle, but I switched to using property list files, which I thought was working much better. But now I'm running into a problem.

Starting up the app, it can either create the puzzle pieces from scratch, or it can create them based upon the information from the plist files. When it creates them from scratch, I can put up an activity indicator the is pretty accurate about animating while the processing takes place.

When rebuilding from property list data, though, after all my processing is complete, there continues to be some sort of activity that is delaying the initial display. Using instruments and NSLog statements, I wasn't making any headway in finding the source of the delay.

Just now, however, I decided to pause the app after the NSLog statements indicated my stuff was finished, but before the display completed. I stepped through a random thread, and as I did that, my views suddenly appeared.

That thread (Thread 24) had a description under it called CFPreferences Background Sync Queue. The block on screen when my views appeared is this:

```
libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release:
0x3c6fa114:  push   {r4, r7, lr}
0x3c6fa116:  mov    r4, r0
0x3c6fa118:  add    r7, sp, #4
0x3c6fa11a:  ldr    r1, [r4, #12]
0x3c6fa11c:  blx    r1
0x3c6fa11e:  mov    r0, r4
0x3c6fa120:  pop.w  {r4, r7, lr}
0x3c6fa124:  b.w    0x3c7127dc                ; _Block_release$shim
```

Note that I am not using NSUserDefaults here but am using separate property lists. I use them thusly:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",self.leftImage.imageName]];
NSData *plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
BOOL returnValue = YES;
if(plistData) {
    NSPropertyListFormat format;
    NSDictionary* plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:plistData options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format error:&error];

    if (plist) { .. etc.
```

Here, I use data in plist to create the objects I need using dispatch_async. I am not updating any of the lists retrieved from disk, so I'm not sure what needs to be synchronized, but it seems like the processes causing the delay are related to property list synchronization (just a hunch on my part based upon names I'm seeing).

Any hints on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I added `-(void)didMoveToWindow` to all my UIView subclasses and when triggered, I checked self.window. This supposedly can be used to check if the view has appeared in the window. In all cases, self.window has a value, and the `didMoveToWindow` method gets called before the delay I'm posting about. On the off-chance that autolayout was doing a bunch of stuff, I tried turning it off, but that didn't make a difference. I also made sure to set each dictionary and plist variable to nil as soon as I was finished with their data, and that didn't make a difference either. As you can see, I'm grasping at straws now.

P.P.S. In case it's helpful, here is a [listing of methods called during the delay](http://the-light.com/test/CRPSTATS.TXT). The number in front of each method is the number of times it was called during the delay period. I identified the start of the delay period by calling an empty method called GENERICMARKFORASYNC_***_*__**_ENDOFMARK at the end of each asynchronous block. I had similar marks for the main code, but the asynchronous code, unsurprisingly, finished last. I identified the end of the delay by moving a view after it finally appeared and looking for the pan gesture being recognized in the log.

Comment: Part of my process involves computing pseudorandom numbers using seeds. It's important that sets of 14 consecutive random numbers all be calculated in the same sequence as their seed. To accomplish this, I had dispatched that task synchronously to the main queue. Thinking that possibly this had caused some congestion in the main queue, I just now created a private serial queue for this purpose, but it didn't make a noticeable difference.

Comment: I solved the problem, although I'm not sure why the fix works. In summary, I had an array of dictionaries. I was fast enumerating them, and dispatching some work for each dictionary to a background thread. Removing this threading solved the problem. I suppose the problem was in the overhead of passing the dictionaries back and forth to blocks or something.